# c# winform email progress and cancellation

Tags: c#, winforms, email, progress-bar

Any ideas on to implementing a progress bar type solution for heavy emails? So when heavy attachments are being uploaded a progress bar with actual % or bytes uploaded can be displayed?

Searched on this topic a bit, a third party library [here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_306.asp) supports this kind of thing.

But looking for some piece of actual code or material on how to implement this kind of control.

Please share, if anyone has any insights on this. Thanks.

Comment: Implementing that functionality would require programming directly against sockets, I would assume.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't afford a commercial library, try this open source project: http://mailsystem.codeplex.com

You will have to implement your own report progress functions, it's not in the library.

Comment: Thanks.. going through the code.. seems like a pretty nice library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not make use of [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)? The link you posted allows you to download the entire [project/solution](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_306.asp).